# Post-apocalyptic Movie where Gasoline Was Very Scarce

Tags: story-identification, movie

I wanted to rewatch an old movie but I can't find anything about it. I remember its title in Spanish only: "Los Quemadores" (The Burners?) I don't know how good or accurate this translation was.

This movie was probably filmed in the 70s or 80s (color movie).

In the story gasoline was not available anymore, except for the government. However, there were secret stockpiles that rich guys and other outliers had gathered before gasoline was banned. These outliers used to drive around in their old cars, in the desert. They also used to steal gasoline from each other, and escape from the government that wanted to get a hold on any remaining gas out there.

The plot has common ideas with Mad Max, but the story was probably located in the western United States, not Australia.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This might be [*Firebird 2015 AD*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082381/) (1981); certainly the theme (gasoline restrictions), setting (desert) and timeframe (1980s) seem to fit.

There isn't a lot of information on the IMDb page, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebird_2015_AD) has more details:

> In the year 2015, the US government outlaws the distribution of gasoline to the public, reserving it only for the politicians, the Military and law enforcement. While it is implied this is due to a fuel shortage, later dialogue rebuffs this stating that gasoline is in abundance. Civilians are also banned from owning or using any form of motor vehicle, and those that do are referred to as Burners, and it is shown that this is a form of rebellion. Burners are monitored and dealt with harshly by the DVC; The Department of Vehicle Control.

Note that the rebels who insist on driving cars are called "Burners" which would fit with what you remember as the title.

There are more plot details on the Wikipedia page.  (Note that the reviews are dire, and it only has a 3.4 on IMDb.)

Comment: This is it! I don't mind the reviews. I'm going to watch it again anyway.

Comment: @TheImpaler If you must: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOaxw9KYFcc

Comment: @TheImpaler One of the stars, Darrin McGavin, played "Kolchak, The Night Stalker", an early monster-of-the-week TV series. Worth a watch for that alone.

Comment: Coincidentally I am watching Kolchak right this very minute.