# Which are the 10 states that defy the federal ban on oil for private citizens?

Tags: firebird-2015-ad

Based on [this story ID](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/251595/19561), I've watched the beginning of *[Firebird 2015 AD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebird_2015_AD)* on YouTube. In the opening scene, after the song, we here a newsreader on the radio say

> "Meanwhile in a speech to Congress today, the President deplored the actions of the ten states which have voted to allot oil and gasoline supplies to citizens in defiance of federal law."

Do we ever learn which 10 states? Is this used to provoke images of the US Civil War and are these largely the same states? At least one of the 10 states seems to be Texas.

Comment: I'm enjoying a review headed "*Just like 'Mad Max' but it sucks*" which seems a really good description.